# How do I get recombinant proteins into the nucleus of mammal cells?

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, mammals, synthetic-biology

I know that there are [Nuclear Localisation Sequencenes (NLS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_localization_sequence). They can be taken from endogenous or viral proteins and fused to the N or C terminus of my recombinant protein.

Which is the best one? Which the best short one (so that it can be more easily added with a Primer)? Should it be attached to the N or the C terminus?
Do they influence expression?

I have heard that *size does matter* (Too large wont fit through the nuclear pore, too smalll will diffuse out again). What is the range of protein sizes that can be targeted efficiently?

Comment: To use a N-terminal or a C-terminal tag depends on your protein. I can only say that you can try both and see which one does better.

Comment: It also depends if your protein has important domains on one of the sides. If so, I would start by using the other end to avoid interference.

Comment: Thanks for the general tip. In my case I have seen people putting stuff (including NLS) to both ends of the protein. Here I am really more concerned about transport efficiency.

Comment: I've seen people use 3 NLS sequences in a row, I assume this improves transport efficiency, but they never explained their reasoning.